# Can I restore my SQL Server database to a point before the last full backup with my current backup strategy?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

If I have this backup strategy(weekly full backup and 1 hour log backup), can I restore the database to the green highlighted period of time? Btw, does log backup 2 includes all log records that have their lsn great than the last_lsn of log backup 1?

[image]

---

I did some more test and I think I found the answer. According to the image in the backup schedule, I did an initial full backup, some log backups, then log backup 1, a full backup, log backup 2. I have modifications in between. Use `RESTORE HEADERONLY` to check log backup 1, full backup and log backup 2, below is what I got. As you can see, log backup 2 catches all log records from the last one in log backup 1. If I want to restore to a point in the green highlighted period, I need to use log backup 2, not the full back.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you could do a point-in-time restore.**

You would need the last full backup and all log backups up to the point you need, as log backups do *not* contain all earlier logs (they are in one sense incremental, rather than differential).

**For a week's worth of logs on a busy database, it may take some time to restore.** Therefore a better solution (if you want to stick to weekly fulls) is to do a differential backup every day or twice a day.

This means that you only need the last full backup, the last diff backup, and all logs going forward up to whenever you want to restore.

---

A fairly standard backup cycle on many servers is: full daily, diff 4-6 per day and logs every few minutes. This gives a pretty fast restore time. It also means more importantly, that your maximum data loss is never more than a few minutes, rather than up to an hour.